# How to reposition the Dropdown in a Navbar?

Tags: html, css, navbar, dropdown

***EXPLANATION AT THE BOTTOM***

HTML:

```
<div class = "navbar">
    <a href = "index.php">NON-HOVER</a>
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href = "index.php">HOVER</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content"><a href = "index.php">DROPDOWN</a></div>
</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    overflow: visible;
    background-color: #A10800;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar a:hover {
    background: #D1281F;
    text-decoration: underline; 
}
.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 8px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

**Explanation:**

I want to make a **Navbar** with a **Dropdown** that **doesn't overlap/cover** the **"HOVER"**-bar. I **don't** want to switch out the **"a"** tag for "HOVER" because I also want "HOVER" to be **clickable/visible** when I hover over it like **"NON-HOVER"**. The problem comes when you hover your mouse over "HOVER", which makes "DROPDOWN" cover "HOVER", instead of being placed under "HOVER" so that both "HOVER" and "DROPDOWN" are **visible** and **clickable**. How can I **reposition** "DROPDOWN"/make it **appear under** "HOVER"?

**Here is a better visualization of the problem:**

[When you don't hover over anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwaWK.png)

[When you hover over "HOVER"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzavV.png)

Comment: you are missing some style from your code, in the sample you provided the `.dropdown` element is not covering the hover button

Comment: I put two picture links that show the problem @cMarius. What's the "style" that I'm missing from my code exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `.dropdown` `overflow` to `visible`, or else you won't see the dropdown menu when it is outside of the container.
Set `.dropdown` `position` to `relative` and `.dropdown-content` `top` to `100%` to shift it down by the height of the `.dropdown` element

```css
.navbar {
    overflow: visible;
    background-color: #A10800;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar a:hover {
    background: #D1281F;
    text-decoration: underline; 
}
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 8px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class = "navbar">
    <a href = "index.php">NON-HOVER</a>
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href = "index.php">HOVER</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content"><a href = "index.php">DROPDOWN</a></div>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar {
        overflow: visible;
        background-color: #A10800;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: left;
    }
    .navbar a:hover {
        background: #D1281F;
        text-decoration: underline; 
    }
    /*.dropdown {
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }*/
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class = "navbar">
  <a href = "index.php">NON-HOVER</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href = "index.php">HOVER</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href = "index.php">DROPDOWN</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```